# configuration: why not conf option = file name and conf value = file content

Tags: linux, configuration

Why is one of the Unix paradigms to save both the configuration name (aka attribute name) and the configuration value in configuration files?
An alternative is to save the attribute name in the file name, and only the configuration value inside the file, following the KISS (keep it simple and stupid) principle. Sorting configuration files can still be done with folders. As far as I know, something similar is already implemented with some files inside /proc on linux, although I have never seen it anywhere else. 
As far as I can remember, Unix philosophy says: "Everything is a file". Why not here?

Comment: Because when I configure an application, say `mutt`, I want to open one text file, not ~200...

Comment: I think I already saw such method of configuration, but it didn't gain popularity. We already have text editors, so we have tools to change/look configuration file. With multiple files, we need additional tools, which will not be good as my editor.

Comment: I just wanted to call into question how everything is done on Unix/Linux ;)  BTW: Does mutt really have 200 configuration options that all need to be edited by you from the beginning and that can't be left on their default state?

Comment: Mutt, irssi; there are *lots* of applications that allow for fine grained customisations. Look at people's dot files on github...

Comment: @jasonwryan: You can still write a shell script to edit all the 200 config files "at once".

Comment: This question has two errors as its premises which make it problematic.  First: Systems like Bernstein qmail _do_ use this system of one setting per configuration file; so the idea that _everyone_ has configuration files with a setting syntax that is parsed, is wrong.  Second: The notion that "everything is a file" is not at odds with configuration _files_, simple or complex.

Comment: I guess the answer to my question is: operating systems so far can handle file content better than file names / many files. More specifically, if there are lots of config options: operating systems can handle big files better than many files (just think at e.g. FAT32).

Comment: On Debian, pure-ftpd is configured like that (pure-ftpd-wrapper debian script maps individual conf files to corresponding options to the executable).

Comment: @conrad_heimbold I *could* write a shell script; but that would be an extraordinarily stupid thing to do (compared to the current state, where I just open the file in vim).

Comment: I edited my question to fit more into the rules. I just wanted to know why it has developed in that way (nothing else), and did not say my or ask for your personal opinions why either one of the both is better or worse. Could you delete the "Put on hold" flag, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts here on why configuration files are not exploded, option by option into a format such as:

```
config
    default
        key
        key
        ...
        key
    other
        key
        key
        ...
```

where the first sub directory is a config type and each file inside ('key's here) are all separate config options, each with a value which is the contents of the file. All of these points are just things I have picked up along the way, and there are certainly loads of exceptions.

1. By and large, most UNIX / Linux utilities operate on a single file at a time, *line by line*, and not multiple files. Why? Lots of reasons, but this seems to be the most simple way to handle input. Most files when viewed from a programming interface are just a series of lines. Lines (some text followed by a `\n`, ASCII line feed) are really the most basic unit of data in most applications, not files. **ASIDE:** Consider that your terminal was designed to be printed on paper, line by line as the user worked. Honestly not much has changed in the modern `tty` as it is still treated like a serial interface.
2. Consider a situation where there are lots and lots of configuration options for a complex program like a socket server or other daemon. For the program to have to open hundreds of files to search for possible derivations from defaults incurs two penalties, an open file descriptor limit (easy to get around) and a couple of syscalls per file. The syscalls can add up because a program has to ask the kernal for assistance for both reading and opening files.
3. Updating and editing a file is generally much more simple to do either with traditional editors (of which `ed` is the clear winner :D ), or utilities like `sed` and `awk`. To use traditional editing tools on a host of file-based config options would really be inconvenient. Also searching over lots of options would become an exercise for a user's shell and not the really possible for an editor. If most config options were just simple values, `echo` and some shell IO redirection would be the editor of choice (which if I understand your preferences, might not be that bad of a thing).
4. Comments. Config files can be more comment than option, and I **really** like comments. If config files were exchanged for config directories, folks had better get used to making README files, and then all of the sudden we have a nasty line-based file in there ;)

Overall I would say that file based configuration is just in the bones of UNIX / Linux systems. Could it be done a different way? Sure. Is the current paradigm the best way? It might be for UNIX / Linux systems, but not for another environment where directories replace files as the point of interface with input.

Comment: So I guess the biggest reason (1) is: because Unix / Linux can handle file content better than file names / many files.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the widely-used text editor Vim. Vim has more than 360 options, *plus* many other functionalities which can be configured in various ways. When Vim starts up it reads a handful of initialization files -- a system-wide initialization file, one or two user-specific initialization files, possibly several other files which set up syntax highlighting, menus and so on. With your proposed setup Vim would need to look for (that is, try to open) more than 360 system-wide option-setting files, followed by 360 user-specific option-setting files, and would *still* need to read the regular configuration files, because Vim is scriptable and most interesting functionalities are configured using the scripting language. Trying to open many hundreds of files just to launch a text editor would be rather inefficient.

And now come the real problems. Some options can be set to values which depend on other options; in a regular configuration file that's easy -- just make sure to set them in the right order. With your proposed setup there is no way to make sure that, for example, the option 'compatible' is set before 'backspace'. In a regular configuration file the user can use the scripting language to adapt the values of certain options to the operating environment; this would be awkward to do in your setup.

What you are describing is actually the Windows registry. There is a reason why the registry is stored as a database of sorts and not as a huge number of tiny files.

Comment: I am not describing the Windows registry. The Windows Registry is one big file; my suggestion is to have many conf files that can be put in whatever folder you wish.

Comment: I know that some configuration options can not be put into the schema configuration name = configuration value. For those configuration options, you could still use the "traditional" way of including multiple conf options in one file.

Comment: The Windows registry is a _database_ holding key/value pairs. It is not a huge collection of tiny files exactly because opening zillions of files would bring the system to its knees. You are describing a situation where the filesystem itself is used a database; current filesystems are not optimized for use as databases.

Comment: serialization of config files with zillions of config options and comments also takes some time (although not that much, because the programs have been optimised to do exactly that very fast). It all boils down to the question, what the software / operating system / kernel / file system has been optimised for - handling lots of files or handling big files.